# JSF + jQuery : AJAX Rendering forces a re-binding to client side (jQuery) events

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf-2

This is a repeating issue for me and I have a solution but it is a little messy and i'm wondering if there is a better solution or someway to avoid the problem alltogether.

This issue occurs when I bind from `jQuery` to a DOM component and then re-render that component using `JSF`/`AJAX`.

For example:

```
<h:commandButton>
  <f:ajax render="rerenderedObject" />
</h:commandButton>

<h:panelGroup id="rerenderedObject">
  ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

And on the jQuery side:

```
var componentBound = false;
function bindToClick() {
   if (componentBound === false) {
      componentBound = true;
      $('#rerenderedObject').click(function() { 
        // DO SOMETHING 
      });
   }

}
```

The binding to `click` is lost whenever the `rerenderedObject` gets re-rendered (the button is pushed)

I have managed to overcome this by binding to JSF using this code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data){
        if (data.status === "success") {
            bindToClick();
        }
    });
});
```

And yet there exists the problem of multiple event bindings (since not every ajax event re-renders `rerenderedObject`) hence the componentBound` variable.

This is my solution, I was wondering if anyone had to deal with this and what was your solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead. It'll put a monitor on newly added elements and reapply the same event handler.

```
$('#rerenderedObject').live('click', function() { 
    // DO SOMETHING 
});
```

Comment: Wow! Tnx,  did not expect it to be this easy :-)
So I should just rebind it on `jQuery.ready()`?

Comment: Also, just saw this: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: Oh thanks for the deprecation notice, I haven't used jQuery closely anymore for over a year.